# How to handle displaying objects created at different times/days in rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time, view, models

I've tried searching on this for several hours and I've not found any 'best practice' way to display views.

I'm creating a task-tracking app in which a User has many(1-3) Goals/"lists", each goal/list is a set of Tasks which are set at any time, but should be in advance.

I want the user to be able to browse their tasks by day/week/month.

I know there are some gems which do something similar, IceCube / FullCalendar.

I just wanted to ask, is that the best way to handle something like this? I've not seen any good resources which explain how to handle time.

I'd like to be able to let users browse into the past / future weeks/months and set tasks for then too, but at the moment I wouldn't know how to auto-generate a view for future/past dates and haven't seen any best practice way to handle such a thing mentioned?

Could anyone please share any resources, or show some examples of how I might do this?

Thanks,

Comment: I am not sure there is a best practice, but what I am sure is that you have to pass some params to your controller that set the requested date. And your controller to listen for those params. That's pretty much it for me.

Comment: Thanks @Maxence, I ended up using your solution and the simple_calendar gem.